# How to solve failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I want to seed data on Laravel 6 , using faker .

i try to add data province using API .

my table . id  |  province

```
public function run()
{
    $url_province = "https://api.example.com/province?key=API_KEY"; //this error on here
    $json_str = file_get_contents($url_province);
    $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
    $provinces = [];
    foreach($json_obj->example->results as $province){
      $provinces[] = [
        'id' => $province->province_id,
        'province' => $province->province
      ];
    }
    DB::table('provinces')->insert($provinces);
}
```

but after i run artisan db:seed , having error

> file_get_contents(https://api.example.com/province?
>           key=********************): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

can someone catch my wrong error ? i just try some tutorial from google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see there a space in your URL

> https://api.example.com/province? key=********************

try to remove it and try to access the url from your browser

Comment: thanks solved . in my script i have a new line beetwen key and ? . thx